# SQL Select Substring using Charindex

Tags: sql

I have a large SQL table which has an `ItemID` column and a `Value` column ; the column `Value` contains a date which I want to extract.

This query works fine and returns the date:

```
declare @Value varchar(255)
set @Value = 'Item-Id: 1243223  Date: 5 Oct 2003 1:14:53  From: xx@yahoo.com  To: yy@yahoo.com'
select substring(@Value,CharIndex(' Date: ',@Value) + 7,charindex(' From: ',@Value)-CharIndex(' Date: ',@Value) -7)
```

My question is: how can I run this query on my entire table without using a "declare"?

Something like:

```
select substring(Value, CharIndex(' Date: ', Value) + 7, charindex(' From: ',Value)  - CharIndex(' Date: ', Value) - 7) 
from TableName
```

If I run this query, I get this error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace **@Value** with **FieldName**.

```
select substring(FieldName,CharIndex(' Date: ',FieldName) + 7,charindex(' From: ',FieldName)-CharIndex(' Date: ',FieldName) -7)
```

Where **FieldName** is a name of your column.

That's all!

Complete sample:

```
Declare @tmp TABLE (MyVal varchar(255))

INSERT INTO @tmp (MyVal)
VALUES('Item-Id: 1243223  Date: 5 Oct 2003 1:14:53  From: xx@yahoo.com  To: yy@yahoo.com'),
('Item-Id: 12432885  Date: 3 May 2004 12:14:53  From: xx@yahoo.com  To: yy@yahoo.com'),
(' ')

SELECT substring(MyVal,CharIndex(' Date: ',MyVal) + 7,charindex(' From: ',MyVal)-CharIndex(' Date: ',MyVal) -7) AS MyDate
FROM @tmp 
WHERE CharIndex(' Date: ',MyVal)>0 AND charindex(' From: ',MyVal)>0
```

Comment: I get this error: Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @user3566591, yeah, field holds less data than it could be returned by **Substring** function. Add **WHERE** statement like this: **WHERE NOT FieldName IS NULL**

Comment: I still get the Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function. using the WHERE NOT FieldName IS NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the values in your string don't all match the format you have specified.  You can fix this by using a `case` statement.  Something like this:

```
select (case when value like '% Date: % From: %'
             then substring(Value, CharIndex(' Date: ', Value) + 7,
                            charindex(' From: ', Value) - CharIndex(' Date: ', Value) -7
                           )
        end)
from TableName ;
```

Comment: Why **CASE** in **SELECT**? Simple **WHERE** statement should do the trick.

Comment: I would preference not to use case due to the size of the value field from the real server. Any other ideas?

Comment: @MaciejLos . . . `WHERE` does not do the trick.  There is no guarantee that the filtering in the `WHERE` happens before the calculation in the `SELECT`.

Comment: @user3566591 . . . This fixes your problem.  If you don't want to fix it, then use another solution.  I have no idea why you would not want to use ` case`.